# Rotate object against Gyroscope in Unity

Tags: unity, rotation

I would like to rotate a simple object against the z-rotation of the gyroscope of a smartphone, so that the object will always "look" to the physical floor where the user is standing. After that, I would like to translate that object forward. It should give you the feeling, that the object is attracted by the "real world" gravity.

Here's a small bad sketch I just made for better understanding:
[image]

I have already tried different examples I found on the web, but they were all kinda too complex for my purpose (they were all about rotating the camera in all 3 axes).

Has anyone ever made some simple script for something like that? Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I have already tried some things out, I found a script on the web but it turned out to be "unprecise". I created a cube and attached the script to it, but when you rotate your phone by 180 degrees a few times, you will notice an "offset".

Here's the script:

```
public var gyroSensitivity : float = 50.0;
private var z : float;


function Update() {

    GyroRotation();

    //Move the object
    transform.Translate(0,-.03f,0);
}


function GyroRotation(){
    //get values from the gyroscope
    z = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.z;        
    RotateZee(z);
}

function RotateZee(axis : float){
    transform.RotateAround(transform.position, new Vector3(0,0,1), -axis * Time.deltaTime * gyroSensitivity);
}
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the `gyroSensitivity`, but I need to multiply the value with something or it will rotate only a few degrees.

Comment: How to do this depends on how you get your gyroscope's data.
I suspect that's in three separate axes, (x, y, z) from -1 to +1, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Try using Input.gyro.attitude or Input.gyro.gravity to get a measure of the current orientation of the device (rather than trying to integrate change in orientation over time, which is prone to drift). These properties use the other sensors on the device to try to correct drift errors in the gyroscope alone.

Comment: Yes, but with gyro.attitude I'm unable to react only to the z-axis rotation changes, or at least I'm too dumb for it

Comment: isn't gyro.attitude just a `Vector3` ? that should allow you to just use `transform.rotation = new Vector3(0,0,Input.gyro.attitude.z);`

Comment: (don't know around which axis we are rotating, but you can just as easily slap the input gyro attitude into either other axis of the vector)

Comment: Unfortunately not. gyro.attitude returns a Quaternion.